# Enabling select and copy of text content in PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

What can prevent PDF-1.4 document's content from being selectable and copyable?

I'm generating PDF-1.4 documents using TTF fonts, which are successfully embedded in it (see screenshot below).

[image: Fonts embedded in my PDF]

Yet I can't select and copy the text from the document. I have studied the [PDF-1.4 spec](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf) and found only one mention of copy-protecting the document, which has a prerequisite of first encrypting  it. And I don't encrypt the document.

So, ideally, I'd like to discover an exhaustive list of reasons, that can prevent the PDF text from being copied, and ways to control that.

Comment: maybe you could mention how you are generating the file so that you can get help improving the process.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one reason, you are embedding your fonts partially. The information you are storing there is the minimum required for drawing the glyphs, but it is not enough for allowing text extraction. For example, in Acrobat Professional, optimizing a file for reducing file size will have this effect, since everything that is not strictly required for *presenting* the content will be discarded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. And how can one determine if the fonts are embedded partially?

Comment: It is hard to tell Without knowing which library and programming language you are using. Over-simplifing the problem, we can say that you need the font objects inside the PDF file to provide a "ToUnicode CMAP" object. Please consult the PDF spec for more details, it is a complex topic.